# PHP file_put_contents not working correctly

Tags: php, replace

I have this code and it does not update the file. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$html = file_get_contents('/srv/www/htdocs/code.html');
$lastmon = Date("m", strtotime("first day of previous month"));
$html_r = str_replace('<strong>CODE_'.$lastmon.'</strong>', '<strong>CODE_'.Date("m").'</strong>', $html);
file_put_contents('/srv/www/htdocs/code.html', $html_r);
```

Comment: maybe that's not `file_put_contents` which does not work, but `str_replace`. The function `Date` does not exist, you should use `date` (it works, but the correct spelling is with a `d`). You should `var_dump()` after each line to understand if something is wrong in previous lines.

Comment: I think there is a difference between `Date("m")` which you are using and `date("m")`, which calls the actual function.

Comment: do you have any errors in your errorlog file?

Comment: No errors, even when I had `Date` vs. `date`

Comment: well with `Date` you would have had errors, so what you mean is that you can't find the errors. Add this to the top of your file `ini_set("log_errors", 1); ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");`

Comment: chaging the filepath to something more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = file_get_contents('/srv/www/htdocs/code.html');
$lastmon = date("m", strtotime("first day of previous month"));
$html_r = str_replace('<strong>CODE_'.$lastmon.'</strong>',     '<strong>CODE_'.date("m").'</strong>', $html);
file_put_contents('/srv/www/htdocs/code.html', $html_r);
```

There's a function date() (and a class DateTime) and maybe you don't know that php is case sensitive.

Be sure that:

- the file path is correct
- php has permissions to read from and write to the file

Comment: The most common failing of `file_put_contents` is that the folder does not have the right permissions on Apache systems. always double check the permissions for `Group`

Comment: changed `Date` to `date`, oops. Also made sure path is correct and file has 777 permissions. What else could be the issue in it not modifying the file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found another way to set the code correctly in the template vs. changing the HTML. I will use PHP in the template to retrieve it from the database vs. having to change it on the fly.